# How is Solana able to provide infinite-time storage for a fixed cost?

Tags: rent, economics, cost

How can Solana store something forever for a fixed cost that is reclaimable if you close the account?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, Solana does not guarantee storage forever. Validators rely on snapshots, and might not have all the history available from genesis.

However, because of this, Solana partnered up with ArWeave last year, and all ledger is archived on ArWeave.

All I'm reading is that ArWeave *does* guarantee storage forever for a fixed fee. They have a quite complex incentive system to get that done - but I have never dived all too deep into that territory. It might be a question to ask the ArWeave team.

Answer (score 1):

if an account is closed, that signals to the runtime that the stored data is no longer valuable to its owner and may be discarded

Comment: But you are giving back the entirety of the rent you collected right?

Comment: no.  **rent** is only collected on legacy accounts that were grandfathered in before the requirement that all accounts be rent-exempt was enforced.  any rent collected from these accounts is the validators'.  the **rent-exempt reserve balance** however works by different economic means (scarcity).  _this_ balance is reclaimed upon closing an account

Comment: In either case, the people who stored the accounts for X amounts of time don't get any reward right?